# Switching from Jquery Mobile to AppFramework

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, appframework

I've built a project using Jquery Mobile. JQM seems perfect for fast prototyping but the end result on an iphone 3GS/IOS 5.1 is far from fluid. I've tried a lot of hacks/tricks to make it faster and got rid of transitions but still, I cannot get a satisfying result.

I've been looking around. What I need is a lightweight solution with a decent UI (JQM is perfect for what I need in that domain).

trigger.io and AppFramework seem to be the 2 solutions which are available (maybe I'm missing some others).

I'd like to give AppFramework a go but I'd like to have feedback from people who have made the change.

Thank you.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

### Intro

A larger version of this answer can also be found **[HERE](http://www.gajotres.net/switching-from-a-jquery-mobile-to-appframework/)**.

[**jQuery Mobile**](http://jquerymobile.com/) was never intended to be used only as an HTML5/CSS3 hybrid mobile app framework. On a similar track like its older brother **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)** and [**jQuery UI**](http://jqueryui.com/) it was intended to be used as a robust, responsive solution in the ever growing mobile web application market. What it took from its older brother was an all around browser support. Run it on every possible major platform and it should work just the same.

That same broad browser support also brought another problem and that is platform optimization. Because jQM can't favor specific platforms also means it is not optimized to use most in any of it.

Let us also talk about [**Phonegap**](http://phonegap.com/) a bit. While great app packaging system it becomes a hell hole when used with a larger [**jQuery Mobile**](http://jquerymobile.com/) application. It's like two great parents made a deformed bastard child or to large pluses gave as an even bigger minus.

### Solutions

Like always in human history another groups of developers came to fill this evident hole. And here came <strike>[**jqMobi**](http://www.jqmobi.com/)</strike> (now [**AppFramework**](https://app-framework-software.intel.com/)), [**jqTouch**](http://jqtjs.com/), [**Zepto**](http://zeptojs.com/), [**Sencha Touch**](http://www.sencha.com/), [**Trigger.io**](https://trigger.io/) and others.

#### Good vs ...

Before going any further than jQuery Mobile one thing must be understood, whatever you gain in speed (and trust me you will get it), you will lose in community support. While every earlier mentioned framework has a sizable developer community behind them, all of them combined can't even come close to **jQM**.

With this said, let us delve into specifics. From my experience currently two best solutions as HTML5/CSS3 Android and iOS hybrid app frameworks are **AppFramework** and **Sencha Touch**. First, let me say, they are fast, faster than **jQuery Mobile** will ever be (if jQ developers stay on this course). UI support is similar if not even better in the case of **Sencha Touch**, not to mention UI is more native looking that it is the case with jQuery Mobile. Listviews are faster, scrolling is better, transitions do not stutter.

#### ... bad

Before someone asks why do people then choose to use, **jQuery Mobile** instead? The obvious  reason would be community support and to some extent, this is the truth. But there are some other pressing matters here. While **jQMoby** advertise it self as a truer **jQuery** alternative to **jQuery Mobile** it is a big lie. While still a great an excellent framework they are using this saying as a marketing trick. They have indeed cloned (redone them) a lot of **jQuery** features but this is only a partial job, and veteran **jQuery** developers are going to find them self in a problem. They will not be able to make fully the most of their previous knowledge thus spending more time trying to find how to do something that was supposed to work than working on an app.

On the other hand **Sencha Touch** doesn't suffer from this problem because it has a different, almost alien syntax. Like with **jqMoby** you will need a lot of time to get into its syntax. But have no fear, the result will be satisfactory in the end.

One other thing, unlike jQuery Mobile and **Phonegap**, **AppFramework** and **Sencha Touch** has their native app packaging system. In my humble opinion, this system is better than **Phonegap** because they are made to work with their js frameworks. Only thing **Phonegap** have over them is a HUGE plugin development community.

## Links

**[jQuery vs Zepto vs jQMobi - which one is the fastest?](http://www.codefessions.com/2012/08/performance-of-jquery-compatible-mobile.html?utm_source=MoSync%20developer%20mailing%20list&utm_campaign=76dcada701-Aug_2012_Newsletter&utm_medium=email)**

> In this case jQuery is like jQuery Mobile because test here relays on
> an underlying framework functionality which jQM takes from jQ.

**[Good ranting on jQuery Mobile vs. Sencha Touch](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/future-roadmap-for-jquery-mobile)**

> Title says it all.

**[AppFramework forum](http://forums.appmobi.com/index.php)**

> Only good jqMoby support site

**[Sencha Touch forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?89-Sencha-Touch-2.x-Forums)**

> Only good Sencha Touch support site

## Conclusion

AppFramework is probably the best choice for you. It has a similar
design as jQuery Mobile so the syntax is not going to be a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I had a look at your profile and I have seen that you've given numerous pointers to enhance the use of JQM. I'm going to try each point you raised for a last JQM attempt.

Comment: I had tried sencha touch on mac. First: installation sencha console make my folder "dirty". Test speed on Android, slow and buggy. For speed and small app, i prefer use jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Better late then never: Very good answer! One more little tip though: If you go Appmobi on a large complicated project (like I did), definitely use the one with jQuery. It is only a fraction slower (really not noticeable) but you get all the jQuery functions. I still have pain in my ass for not using the jQuery one (it wasn't there when I started).

Comment: You mention `if jQ developers stay on this course`. By looking at jQM's roadmap, isn't it true that the coming versions will be all about removing clutter and making things faster?

Comment: 1.4 already started with removing and it's a lot faster then 1.3, 1.5 will go same way plus they will add some new stuff.