# Phonegap and the universe of frameworks?

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, cordova, requirejs, underscore.js

my concern is to find a well fitting framework for developing a cross mobile platform app via phonegap. I am using JQMobile for the User interface.

I want to build my Application well structured and modular. That means i want to keep it very well capsulated.

I know Backbone.js , Underscore.js , handlebar.js , Mustache.js.... and many more.

I am wondering what could be the best method of structuring my apps architecture?! Moreover: Are there big dependencies which result from using those frameworks?
Which framework is giving me the BEST expandability and performance Boosts?

Iam asking because i hope someone can give me a hint. That would save much time.

Greetings

Chris.

EDIT: USEFUL Information for readers.

My final decision is based on "http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/". This is a Tutorial about developing a Phonegap Application. Christophe Coenraets is a Technical Evangelist from Adobe. He gives many advices how to develop Phonegap applications with good performance. The link directs you to a really nice Tutorial for Routing between Views, Css Scrolling with Phonegap and many architectural information more. There is also a 60 minute presentation about Performance / Architecture and more similiar stuff. I am using handlebars.js for HTML templating, fastclick.js to simulate "touch" for "click" for more performance and Twitter Bootstrap CSS Framework for the responsive Design.

Anyway thx for your answers!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First lets make something clear. Whatever you use, you will not gain performance boost. Even worse, there's a good chance your performances will be lower.

But what you will get is usability and readability + more functional code than it is the case with pure jQuery + jQuery Mobile.

The most commonly used combination is jQuery Mobile + Backbone + Require.js. From my experience, it is also the best one. Unfortunately, in the end, I think you will be disappointed. While this is an excellent combination, jQuery Mobile applications are usually slugish on Phonegap. So think about it.

I have several other articles discussing similar topic so take a look:

**[Switching from Jquery Mobile to AppFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16499979/1848600)**

**[Which mobile development open source Framework should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16357099/1848600)**

Comment: but jQuery Mobile has problem with fixed header and footer on phonegap, isn't it?

Comment: Only oldest Android versions are affected by this problem. It can be solved up to the point if header or footer is replaced with native navbar plugin for Phonegap.

Comment: another +1 for the navbar comment!